# How include a filefield in a django admin model form that is not in the model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I want to include a filefield in an admin model form that will be used to uploaded a file that will then be read and the contents will be used to update other fields in the same model. After processing the file itself is not needed, so i don't want the filefield in the model just in the form.

I have no problem overriding save and processing the form myself, but I can't figure out how to include a filefield in my form that is not in the model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create a [ModelForm for this model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), and add the field there. It could look like this:

```
from django import forms

from models import MyModel

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_file = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Then, you can [make the ModelAdmin to use this form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form). If you saved MyModelForm in yourapp/forms.py, your ModelAdmin would look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from models import MyModel
from forms import MyModelForm

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```